# How to call method with id object parameter in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I created a protocol and a method that add classes. But when I want to add class by this method I have an error : 
**implicit conversion of an objective-c pointer to '__autoreleasing id *' is disallowed with arc**

```
 self.homeViewController = [[HomeViewController alloc] init];   
 [DataController addProgressListener:self.homeViewController];
```

**MyProtocol class**

```
- (void) addProgressListener:(id*)idbProgressListener {
        if(self.progressListeners == nil)
            self.progressListeners = [NSMutableArray<IDBProgressListener> alloc];

        [self.progressListeners addObject:*idbProgressListener];
    }
```

Comment: remove the pointer in the method in your protocol classs.
`id`and not `*id`, and tell me what happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With id you don't have to use a *. id internally has a pointer allocated to itself. You don't need to explicitly pass it.

Comment: What Jaycee means is that `id` is essentially a typedef for `(void*)`, which means it's already a pointer type.  Writing `id *` is defining a pointer to a pointer, which is not what you intended.

Comment: It works. But it gives me error like this  :[DataController addProgressListener:]: unrecognized selector sent to class

Comment: Not really void*, but something very similar to NSObject* (it's not exactly the same, but close enough for most purposes).

Comment: DataController is not an instance, it's a class. There is an instance method addProgressListener:, but no class method (wouldn't make much sense anyway).

Comment: Yeah sure. I have missed this. Thanks. :)